# Short-Cut Mongoose Update Method Validation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing a webApp with Mongoose and inside my JS File that offers CRUD methods, I got this part, where I validate the user input for cases when it would be "not null" and then send the data to the database.

Now would there be a way to shortcut the following code, because I have very huge Tables, with lots of "Attributes" (JSON Members).

```
update_MY_collection = function(req, res) {

 console.log("PUT - /my_data/:id");

 return MY_collection.findById(req.params.id, function(err, my_collection) {

  if(!my_collection) {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    return res.send({ error: 'Not found' });
  }

  if (req.body.n1 != null) my_collection.item1 = req.body.item1;
  if (req.body.n2 != null)  my_collection.different_item2 = req.body.different_item2;
  if (req.body.n3 != null)  my_collection.item3_different = req.body.item3_different;
  // .....
  if (req.body.n != null) ip_vermarktung.Auftragsnr = req.body.Auftragsnr;
  // with n > 30 items

  return my_collection.save(function(err) {
    if(!err) {
      console.log('Updated');
      return res.send({ status: 'OK', my_collection:my_collection });
    } else {
      if(err.name == 'ValidationError') {
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.send({ error: 'Validation error' });
      } else {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.send({ error: 'Server error' });
      }
      console.log('Internal error(%d): %s',res.statusCode,err.message);
    }

    res.send(my_collection);

  });
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Use mongoose's built in `validation`. Check out [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) . This way you can create validation methods [at schema level](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate) once and for all and use them [across the application](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-validate) and also have a look at [the middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).